# Procedure expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm getting the error when accessing a Stored Procedure in SQL Server

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Procedure or function 'ColumnSeek' expects parameter '@template', which was not supplied.
```

This is happening when I call a Stored Procedure with a parameter through .net's data connection to sql `(System.data.SqlClient)`, even though I am supplying the parameter. Here is my code.

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connPath);
sqlConn.Open();

//METADATA RETRIEVAL
string sqlCommString = "QCApp.dbo.ColumnSeek";
SqlCommand metaDataComm = new SqlCommand(sqlCommString, sqlConn);
metaDataComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter sp = metaDataComm.Parameters.Add("@template",SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
sp.Value = Template;

SqlDataReader metadr = metaDataComm.ExecuteReader();
```

And my Stored Procedure is:

```
   USE [QCApp]
   GO
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO

   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ColumnSeek] 
       @template varchar(50)
   AS
   EXEC('SELECT Column_Name, Data_Type 
   FROM [QCApp].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = ' + @template);
```

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

**Edit:** As it turns out, Template was null because I was getting its value from a parameter passed through the URL and I screwed up the url param passing (I was using `@` for and instead of `&`)

Comment: Very old question, but I encountered the same problem, and in my case, I didn't see I added an extra space in one of the @parameter. One hour of debugging.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26374810/1860652 for executing stored procedures and getting this error

Comment: This ended up on the front page today for whatever reason.  But it sounds like this is vulnerable to SQL injection if the "template" value is coming from the client URL!  At the very least I would suggesting using `QUOTENAME(@template)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/368677/5954471

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I would check my application code and see what value you are setting @template to. I suspect it is null and therein lies the problem.

Comment: Yeah, Template was null, I forgot to set it earlier.

Comment: Can I just add that DbNull is the SINGLE most useless "feature" of C#

Comment: Check also the parameter name in both code and sp, they can be different.

Answer (score 344):

In addition to the other answers here, if you've forgotten to put:

```cs
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Then you will also get this error.

Comment: If you are debugging it from Visual Studio: On report's data tab [beside layout and Preview tabs] next to the name of the dataset selected, there is another drop down control that lets you change the CommandType. Enjoy!

Comment: yes, the SqlException is weird - it tells you that it knows it as a procedure but then you have to set it's CommandType property to tell it that it is a procedure!

Comment: @Tahir, I think it's more that the error is using "procedure" as a generic term (as suggested by the addition of "or function"), rather than implicating it's aware the intent is a SQL DB stored procedure.

Comment: this is the solution for 99% of the people coming here I imagine

Comment: Dammit, why was the solution this easy. Thank you. I knew the parameter existed and wasn't null and this was all it took.

Comment: This is weird. Sometimes it doesn't raise such error and sometimes it doesn't let you go without explicitly telling it the command type. Anyways, Thanks.

Comment: Holly Moley! - there goes 50 minutes. I cut and pasted some known code - left out the CommandType.StoredProcedure. Was about to have a brain aneurysm and throw my keyboard out the window. Used this code for years and years and somehow left out the CommandType. Well, this will NEVER EVER happen to me again. Thank you for this answer and post, it is appreciated.

Comment: Haven't programmed in over 5 years. @Jonesopolis nailed it. I'd feel moronic but the 99% remark is also probably accurate. Thanks.

Comment: Amazing how something so simple can escape us at times.  I've written SQL commands for a very long time, and I never forgot the `CommandType`.  Until today.  Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

This issue is indeed usually caused by setting a parameter value to null as **HLGEM** mentioned above.  I thought i would elaborate on some solutions to this problem that i have found useful for the benefit of people new to this problem.

The solution that i prefer is to default the stored procedure parameters to NULL (or whatever value you want), which was mentioned by **sangram** above, but may be missed because the answer is very verbose.  Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmployeeDetails
    @DateOfBirth    DATETIME = NULL,
    @Surname        VARCHAR(20),
    @GenderCode     INT = NULL,
AS
```

This means that if the parameter ends up being set in code to null under some conditions, .NET will not set the parameter and the stored procedure will then use the default value it has defined.  Another solution, if you really want to solve the problem in code, would be to use an extension method that handles the problem for you, something like:

```
public static SqlParameter AddParameter<T>(this SqlParameterCollection parameters, string parameterName, T value) where T : class
{
    return value == null ? parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, DBNull.Value) : parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, value);
}
```

Matt Hamilton has a good post [here](http://madprops.org/blog/addwithvalue-via-extension-methods/) that lists some more great extension methods when dealing with this area.

Answer (score 12):

I had a problem where I would get the error when I supplied 0 to an integer param. And found that:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", 0);
```

works, but this does not:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", 0));
```

Comment: The reason the 2nd one doesn't work is because the compiler thinks you're calling the *(string, SqlDbType)* overload of the SqlParameter constructor. See remarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If you wanted to use the `Add` syntax, or you were using an object initializer for your command, you could use a named parameter: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", value: 0));`

Answer (score 10):

For my case, I had to pass `DBNULL.Value`(using if else condition) from code for stored procedures parameter that are not defined `null` but value is  `null`.

Answer (score 5):

I come across similar problem while calling stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UserPreference_Search
    @UserPreferencesId int,
    @SpecialOfferMails char(1),
    @NewsLetters char(1),
    @UserLoginId int,
    @Currency varchar(50)
AS
DECLARE @QueryString nvarchar(4000)

SET @QueryString = 'SELECT UserPreferencesId,SpecialOfferMails,NewsLetters,UserLoginId,Currency FROM UserPreference'
IF(@UserPreferencesId IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE UserPreferencesId = @DummyUserPreferencesId';
END

IF(@SpecialOfferMails IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE SpecialOfferMails = @DummySpecialOfferMails';
END

IF(@NewsLetters IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE NewsLetters = @DummyNewsLetters';
END

IF(@UserLoginId IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE UserLoginId = @DummyUserLoginId';
END

IF(@Currency IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE Currency = @DummyCurrency';
END

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @QueryString
                     ,N'@DummyUserPreferencesId int, @DummySpecialOfferMails char(1), @DummyNewsLetters char(1), @DummyUserLoginId int, @DummyCurrency varchar(50)'
                     ,@DummyUserPreferencesId=@UserPreferencesId
                     ,@DummySpecialOfferMails=@SpecialOfferMails
                     ,@DummyNewsLetters=@NewsLetters
                     ,@DummyUserLoginId=@UserLoginId
                     ,@DummyCurrency=@Currency;
```

Which dynamically constructing the query for search I was calling above one by:

```
public DataSet Search(int? AccessRightId, int? RoleId, int? ModuleId, char? CanAdd, char? CanEdit, char? CanDelete, DateTime? CreatedDatetime, DateTime? LastAccessDatetime, char? Deleted)
    {
        dbManager.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MSSQL"].ToString();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            dbManager.Open();
            dbManager.CreateParameters(9);
            dbManager.AddParameters(0, "@AccessRightId", AccessRightId, ParameterDirection.Input);
            dbManager.AddParameters(1, "@RoleId", RoleId, ParameterDirection.Input);
            dbManager.AddParameters(2, "@ModuleId", ModuleId, ParameterDirection.Input);
            dbManager.AddParameters(3, "@CanAdd", CanAdd, ParameterDirection.Input);
            dbManager.AddParameters(4, "@CanEdit", CanEdit, ParameterDirection.Input);
            dbManager.AddParameters(5, "@CanDelete", CanDelete, ParameterDirection.Input);
            dbManager.AddParameters(6, "@CreatedDatetime", CreatedDatetime, ParameterDirection.Input);
            dbManager.AddParameters(7, "@LastAccessDatetime", LastAccessDatetime, ParameterDirection.Input);
            dbManager.AddParameters(8, "@Deleted", Deleted, ParameterDirection.Input);
            ds = dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "AccessRight_Search");
            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            dbManager.Dispose();
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Then after lot of head scratching I modified stored procedure to:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AccessRight_Search]
    @AccessRightId int=null,
    @RoleId int=null,
    @ModuleId int=null,
    @CanAdd char(1)=null,
    @CanEdit char(1)=null,
    @CanDelete char(1)=null,
    @CreatedDatetime datetime=null,
    @LastAccessDatetime datetime=null,
    @Deleted char(1)=null
AS
DECLARE @QueryString nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @HasWhere bit
SET @HasWhere=0

SET @QueryString = 'SELECT a.AccessRightId, a.RoleId,a.ModuleId, a.CanAdd, a.CanEdit, a.CanDelete, a.CreatedDatetime, a.LastAccessDatetime, a.Deleted, b.RoleName, c.ModuleName FROM AccessRight a, Role b, Module c WHERE a.RoleId = b.RoleId AND a.ModuleId = c.ModuleId'

SET @HasWhere=1;

IF(@AccessRightId IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        IF(@HasWhere=0) 
            BEGIN
                SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE a.AccessRightId = @DummyAccessRightId';
                SET @HasWhere=1;
            END
        ELSE                SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' AND a.AccessRightId = @DummyAccessRightId';
    END

IF(@RoleId IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        IF(@HasWhere=0)
            BEGIN   
                SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE a.RoleId = @DummyRoleId';
                SET @HasWhere=1;
            END
        ELSE            SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' AND a.RoleId = @DummyRoleId';
    END

IF(@ModuleId IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    IF(@HasWhere=0) 
            BEGIN   
                SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE a.ModuleId = @DummyModuleId';
                SET @HasWhere=1;
            END
    ELSE SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' AND a.ModuleId = @DummyModuleId';
END

IF(@CanAdd IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    IF(@HasWhere=0) 
            BEGIN       
                SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE a.CanAdd = @DummyCanAdd';
                SET @HasWhere=1;
            END
    ELSE SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' AND a.CanAdd = @DummyCanAdd';
END

IF(@CanEdit IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    IF(@HasWhere=0) 
        BEGIN
            SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE a.CanEdit = @DummyCanEdit';
            SET @HasWhere=1;
        END
    ELSE SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' AND a.CanEdit = @DummyCanEdit';
END

IF(@CanDelete IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    IF(@HasWhere=0) 
        BEGIN
            SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE a.CanDelete = @DummyCanDelete';
            SET @HasWhere=1;
        END
    ELSE SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' AND a.CanDelete = @DummyCanDelete';
END

IF(@CreatedDatetime IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    IF(@HasWhere=0) 
    BEGIN
        SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE a.CreatedDatetime = @DummyCreatedDatetime';
        SET @HasWhere=1;
    END
    ELSE SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' AND a.CreatedDatetime = @DummyCreatedDatetime';
END

IF(@LastAccessDatetime IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    IF(@HasWhere=0) 
        BEGIN
            SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE a.LastAccessDatetime = @DummyLastAccessDatetime';
            SET @HasWhere=1;
        END
    ELSE SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' AND a.LastAccessDatetime = @DummyLastAccessDatetime';
END

IF(@Deleted IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  IF(@HasWhere=0)   
    BEGIN
        SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' WHERE a.Deleted = @DummyDeleted';
        SET @HasWhere=1;
    END
  ELSE SET @QueryString = @QueryString + ' AND a.Deleted = @DummyDeleted';
END

PRINT @QueryString

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @QueryString
                      ,N'@DummyAccessRightId int, @DummyRoleId int, @DummyModuleId int, @DummyCanAdd char(1), @DummyCanEdit char(1), @DummyCanDelete char(1), @DummyCreatedDatetime datetime, @DummyLastAccessDatetime datetime, @DummyDeleted char(1)'
                      ,@DummyAccessRightId=@AccessRightId
                      ,@DummyRoleId=@RoleId
                      ,@DummyModuleId=@ModuleId
                      ,@DummyCanAdd=@CanAdd
                      ,@DummyCanEdit=@CanEdit
                      ,@DummyCanDelete=@CanDelete
                      ,@DummyCreatedDatetime=@CreatedDatetime
                      ,@DummyLastAccessDatetime=@LastAccessDatetime
                      ,@DummyDeleted=@Deleted;
```

HERE I am Initializing  the Input Params of Stored Procedure to null as Follows

```
    @AccessRightId int=null,
@RoleId int=null,
@ModuleId int=null,
@CanAdd char(1)=null,
@CanEdit char(1)=null,
@CanDelete char(1)=null,
@CreatedDatetime datetime=null,
@LastAccessDatetime datetime=null,
@Deleted char(1)=null
```

that did the trick for Me.

I hope this will be helpfull to someone who fall in similar trap.

Answer (score 4):

I came across same issue. And my parameter was having null value. So I resolved by handling null value. If someone is not sure runtime value and want to handle null then simply use this. (And you don't want to change the SP/function.) E.g.

```
sp.Value = Template ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

If Template is not set (i.e. ==null), this error will be raised, too.

More comments:

If you know the parameter value by the time you add parameters, you can also use AddWithValue

The EXEC is not required. You can reference the @template parameter in the SELECT directly.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone comes across, googling. If you're getting this error up despite having the default parameter value defined (which should allow you to run the procedure without explicitly passing that parameter), double check if you actually did set the default value, as this:

```
@someTextParameter NVARCHAR(100) NULL
```

only lets the parameter accept `NULL` as input, while this:

```
@someTextParameter NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
```

is actually declaring parameter optional.

It's a silly mistake, overlooking which costed me half an hour ;)

Answer (score 0):

First - why is that an EXEC? Shouldn't that just be

```
AS
SELECT Column_Name, ...
FROM ...
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @template
```

The current SP doesn't make sense? In particular, that would look for a **column** matching @template, not the varchar value of @template. i.e. if @template is `'Column_Name'`, it would search `WHERE TABLE_NAME = Column_Name`, which is very rare (to have table and column named the same).

Also, if you *do* have to use dynamic SQL, you should use `EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL` (keeping the values as parameters) to prevent from injection attacks (rather than concatenation of input). But it isn't necessary in this case.

Re the actual problem - it looks OK from a glance; are you sure you don't have a different copy of the SP hanging around? This is a common error...

Comment: It still doesn't work with that change. 

I had the exec because I was working previously with a proc where the from clause was supplied from a param so I got thinking wrongly on this one. But I still get the error with just the select

Comment: very curious; perhaps treble-check for typos?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, to solve it just add exactly the same parameter name to your parameter collection as in your stored procedures.

Example

Let's say you create a stored procedure:

```
create procedure up_select_employe_by_ID 
     (@ID int) 
as
    select * 
    from employe_t 
    where employeID = @ID
```

So be sure to name your parameter exactly as it is in your stored procedure this would be

```
cmd.parameter.add("@ID", sqltype,size).value = @ID
```

if you go

```
cmd.parameter.add("@employeID", sqltype,size).value = @employeid
```

then the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error today when null values were passed to my stored procedure's parameters. I was able easily fix by altering the stored procedure by adding default value = null.