# SQL Query says a parameter is not supplied, but is added to the SqlCommand object

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net

I have a stored procedure that has a parameter called UserName and in my code behind I have a SqlCommand object that I add the parameters to with the Add method. But for some reason when the command object tries to run the ExecuteReader method, it throws an exception. I am totally at a loss and have no idea why it's not recognizing the parameter. Before the ExecuteReader method is run I have a break point set so I can confirm the command object does contain the parameters being set, which is true. I know the stored procedure does return the correct data when the parameters are not added to the command object, but are hard coded in the actual stored procedure. Below is the exception message that is given in the catch block. I will also paste my code and first part of stored procedure. I would greatly appreciate any help in this issue, seeing that I have tried many different approaches to no avail. Thanks in advance.

### Exception Message

Procedure or function 'someStoredProcedure' expects parameter '@UserName', which was not supplied.

### Code Behind

```
private DataTable GetLossMitData(string code, DateTime? start, DateTime? end)  
{  
DataTable results = new DataTable();  
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["asdf"].ConnectionString;  
string userName = String.Empty;  

try  
{  
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someName"]))  
    {  
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())  
        {  
            userName = web.CurrentUser.Email.ToString();  
        }  
    }  

    using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
    {  
         connection1.Open();  
         using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("someStoredProcedure", connection1))  
         {  
             command1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", userName));  
             command1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductCode", code));  

             SqlDataReader dr = command1.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);  
             results.Load(dr);  
         }  
         connection1.Close();  
    }  
}  
catch (Exception ex)  
{  
}  
return results;  
}
```

### Stored Procedure

```
@UserName nvarchar(256),  
@ProductCode nvarchar(256),
@StartDate nvarchar(256) = '1/1/1900',
@EndDate nvarchar(256) = '12/30/2012'

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @UserID int

Select @UserID = Users.UserID
from Users
where Users.Email = @UserName
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Procedure expects parameter which was not supplied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368642/procedure-expects-parameter-which-was-not-supplied)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try making sure that the command type is set to stored procedure.

```
mycommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: You get an "Incorrect syntax near..." error if it's not set to StoredProcedure, so I don't think it's this

Comment: @Ray's answer doesn't make sense given the context.  If the command type is set to Text, then calling this stored procedure will never work unless you do something like @SLaks suggested by placing the parameters within the statement.  Changing the command type to stored procedure should most definitely work.

Comment: If anything, getting an error whenever the command type is not set to stored procedure only seems to provide more evidence that this is in fact the issue.

Comment: The error message returned by sql server indicates that it knows that the command is a stored proc call. I agree with you that it should be explicitly setup in the command object so sql server doesn't have to guess, but I don't think this causes the error.

Comment: @Ray - The reason that this does cause the issue is because you're sending SQL a text command like "exec SPROC".  If SPROC is supposed to accept parameters and you do not specify those parameters within the text command, then the command type must be changed to stored procedure so that it can be sent to the SQL server correctly.  That is why OP got an "expects parameter" error.

Comment: @Aaron - I see what you mean, but it causes a different error for me. When I remove the commandType for an otherwise functioning command, I get a sql syntax error (I can see it while watching the profiler). I wonder how, in the original question, sql server knew that a stored proc was being called.

Comment: +1 as I've also reproduced it giving the same error. There are it seems multiple ways to get this error, and interestingly it matters what version of SQL Server you are using!

Comment: @AdaTheDev I'm surprised nobody has called out your first comment. Are you saying that intellisense is smart enough to know that an SqlCommand has to have its CommandType property set to CommandType.StoredProcedure for you to be able to add SqlParameters to the SqlCommand.Parameters collection?

Comment: @Zack - No that's not what I was saying (I wasn't talking about intellisense, rather a runtime exception). Based on how the OP was creating the command specifying JUST the sproc name, the CommandType would have needed to be set to CommandType.StoredProcedure. But from what I investigated at the time, it didn't initially appear consistent with the error message that the OP was reporting.

Comment: I have no idea why I needed to do this since the error message I got had nothing to do with whether I was invoking a stored proc or not, but this answer Helped Me so +1.

Answer (score 10):

You will get this exception if the value of your 'userName' variable is null

If null is valid, then pass 'DBNull.Value' to the db instead:

```
command1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", (userName ?? DBNull.Value));
```

Comment: Wrong.  That's not the problem here, and it wouldn't throw this exception anyway.

Comment: @SLaks - Your downvote is a bit hasty - I make this mistake all too frequently, and this is the exception that I get to spank me

Comment: Actually, I didn't downvote; somebody else did.  However, you're still wrong.

Comment: userName is not null and should never be null as long as they have logged in. But I say should as if anything in code is ever certain. But I will add that just in case. Thanks

Comment: @Slaks - Sorry for the assumption.  @jhorton - "should never be null" - I have said that myself once or twice, which is why I have seen this same exception happen to me.

Comment: @jhorton - it sounds like you do not want to use my DBNull.Value suggestion if you have a null userName - if you are always supposed to have a value, then you will probably want to test for null elsewhere and throw your own exception.

Comment: I have to still agree with @Ray. I was sure I've had this myself in the past, so I've just knocked up a test to make sure - when I set a parameter in this way using null as the value, it **does** end up throwing this exact error. So, still +1 from me!

Comment: I just tried it and got the exception. @SLaks - do you have a default value for the parameter in your stored proc? If so, you won't get this error.

Comment: Just because it works with default values does not mean that this is logically the right choice.  I believe that if you define default values it will in fact work; however, the default values will be used instead of any passed ones unless you change the command type to stored procedure.

Comment: No, I don't.  What exactly did you try?

Comment: @Ray - I will be using the DBNull suggestion, so I do appreciate the suggestion. But the actual fix is declaring the command type. So the DBNull actually fixes my second issue. So I will mark this as an answer as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @Slaks - I modified a working command parameter like this, just to force the issue: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter_name", null); When I ran the command I got the exception. When I returned the parameter to its original state (with a proper value) the exception went away.

Comment: God, saved my life

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `CommandText` property needs to contain a complete SQL command, not  just the name of the stored procedure.

You can change this by to set the `SqlCommand`'s [`CommandType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype.aspx) property to `StoredProcedure`.

Alternatively, you could explicitly pass the parameters, by changing the `CommandText` to `"someStoredProcedure @UserName, @ProductCode"`; this is a complete SQL statement and will work with the default `CommandType` of `Text`.

**EDIT**: I just tried it, and the only way to get that error message without setting `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure` (which he did not do) is if `CommandText` is `EXEC someStoredProcedure`.  Passing a `null` parameter gives a different error.

Comment: You get an "Incorrect syntax near..." error if it's not set to StoredProcedure, so I don't think it's this. I've reproduced the error as given by OP, using @Ray's answer so I think he may be correct

Comment: +1 as I've reproduced also it this way now. It appears it matters what version of SQL Server you're using - SQL 2008 reports this as the error given by the OP. In SQL 2000 (and I think 2005 though I need to recheck), it's reported as I said in my comment above - "Incorrect syntax...". Think I may knock up a blog post on this!

Answer (score 3):

```
Command1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

This will force the ExecuteReader to perform the exec instead of just trying it as a flat command.

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET provides classes to run the DB operations in .NET platform and handle the results with several methods. One the important parts is executing related command in database & retrieve the result of it. ADO.NET provides SqlCommand class for this part of operations.

Based on your choose & design of code, there are several ways to manage this. I believe the best way is writing Stored Procedures in your database & execute them in your code. For making the correct code you need to set these parts in your SqlCommand object:

1 - Connection (provide the connection to database)

2 - CommandType (detect your choose for executing type like simple text or stored procedure)

3 - CommandText (based on CommandType, it can be the name of stored procedure or full database command text)

If your command includes parameters (stored procedure or simple text), you have to add them in Parameters object of SqlCommand. Now you can run your command on database & retrieve the result.

For reading data for example you can choose ExecuteReader() method (there are another ways with some differences too) and for DML operations you can use ExecuteNonQuery() method of SqlCommand object.

If you did it in right way, it should work properly without problem.

Note: these classes are in System.Data.SqlClient namespace & optimized for Sql Server. For another vendors you can use similar classes in System.Data.Common package (modern .NET).