# Procedure expects parameter even though the parameter is provided

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I saw that some others faced this similar problem. I have read and checked the question titled [Procedure expects parameter which was not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368642/procedure-expects-parameter-which-was-not-supplied). I thought it would solve my problem but I was wrong :( I did check the steps that were advised there with no luck. Here is my code:

```
oOleDbCommand.CommandText = "usp_PettyCash_AddBillInfo";
oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@BillID", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = nBillID;
oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@SerialNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = sSerialNo;
oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@UniqueID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = oInputBill[0].UniqueID.ToString();
oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@BilledWeekDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = oInputBill[0].BilledWeekDate;
oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@BilledWeekNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = oInputBill[0].BilledWeekNo.ToString();
oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@SettledWeekDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = oInputBill[0].SettledWeekDate;
oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@SettledWeekNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = oInputBill[0].SettledWeekNo;
oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@BillStatus", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = oInputBill[0].BillStatus.ToString();
oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedBy", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = oInputBill[0].UpdatedBy;
oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@UpdateDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = oInputBill[0].UpdateDate;
```

Stored Procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_PettyCash_AddBillInfo 
(
    @BillID bigint,
    @SerialNo varchar(50),
    @UniqueID varchar(50),
    @BilledWeekDate datetime,
    @BilledWeekNo varchar(50),
    @SettledWeekDate datetime,
    @SettledWeekNo varchar(50),
    @BillStatus varchar(50),
    @UpdatedBy varchar(50),
    @UpdateDate datetime 
)
AS

BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO t_BillInfo (BillID, SerialNo, UniqueID, BilledWeekDate, BilledWeekNo, SettledWeekDate, SettledWeekNo, BillStatus, UpdatedBy, UpdateDate) 
    VALUES (@BillID, @SerialNo, @UniqueID, @BilledWeekDate, @BilledWeekNo, @SettledWeekDate, @SettledWeekNo, @BillStatus, @UpdatedBy, @UpdateDate) 
END 

GO
```

While debugging, i found the value of `nBillID = 1.0` and `sSerialNo='B201200001'`. But when trying to execute the `ExecuteNonQuery` command, it gives the exception:

> "Procedure 'usp_PettyCash_AddBillInfo' expects parameter '@BillID',
>   which was not supplied."

I can't find any workarounds. Please help. Sorry for re-asking the question.

As a workaround, I used this:

```
oOleDbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t_BillInfo (BillID, SerialNo, UniqueID, BilledWeekDate, BilledWeekNo, SettledWeekDate, SettledWeekNo, BillStatus, UpdatedBy, UpdateDate)"+
" VALUES (" + nBillID + ", '" + sSerialNo + "', '" + oInputBill[0].UniqueID.ToString() + "','" + oInputBill[0].BilledWeekDate.ToShortDateString() + "', '" + oInputBill[0].BilledWeekNo + "', '" + oInputBill[0].SettledWeekDate.ToShortDateString() + "', '" + oInputBill[0].SettledWeekNo + "', '" + oInputBill[0].BillStatus.ToString() + "', '" + oInputBill[0].UpdatedBy + "', '" + oInputBill[0].UpdateDate.ToShortDateString() + "')";
```

Although I did not like this type of coding, but this works.

Comment: Well one thing that jumps to my eye: you're defining parameters as type `OleDbType.VarChar` - but you're not defining any **length!** That means those parameters will be **1 character long** - probably **not** what you wanted ..... you need to **specify the desired length** like this: `oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@SerialNo", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = .....`

Comment: So I assume you've already tried to add `oOleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`, correct?

Comment: @ Enrico, Yes. @ marc_s, i tried that too, but no change :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

```
oOleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

I believe without this, your parameter values are supposed to be added inline (like an inline SQL statement). E.g:

```
oOleDbCommand.CommandText = "usp_PettyCash_AddBillInfo @BillID, @SerialNo...";
```

So your adding your parameters to the command, but they are not in the CommandText, so they're not being applied anywhere.

> To call a stored procedure, set the **CommandType** of the Command object
>   to **StoredProcedure**. Once the CommandType is set to StoredProcedure,
>   you can use the Parameters collection to define parameters, as in the
>   following example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You don't believe it, I restarted my pc hoping some childish luck and after this, all is working :) I guess there might be some case with SQL server caching (i have no idea about it, i just guess)