# Stored procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert data into a SQL Server database by calling a stored procedure, but I am getting the error

> Procedure or function 'SHOWuser' expects parameter '@userID', which was not supplied.

My stored procedure is called `SHOWuser`. I have checked it thoroughly and no parameters is missing.

My code is:

```
public void SHOWuser(string userName, string password, string emailAddress, List<int> preferences)
{
        SqlConnection dbcon = new SqlConnection(conn);

        try
        { 
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.Connection = dbcon;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "SHOWuser";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", emailAddress);

            dbcon.Open();

            int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.CommandText = "tbl_pref";

            foreach (int preference in preferences)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", Convert.ToInt32(i));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preferenceID", Convert.ToInt32(preference));

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            dbcon.Close();
        }
```

and the stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SHOWuser]
(
    @userName varchar(50),
    @password nvarchar(50),
    @emailAddress nvarchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_user(userName, password, emailAddress) 
    VALUES (@userName, @password, @emailAddress)

    SELECT
        tbl_user.userID, tbl_user.userName,
        tbl_user.password, tbl_user.emailAddress, 
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + preferenceName 
               FROM tbl_pref_master
               INNER JOIN tbl_preferences ON tbl_pref_master.preferenceID = tbl_preferences.preferenceID
               WHERE tbl_preferences.userID = tbl_user.userID
               FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ' ' ) AS Preferences
    FROM
        tbl_user

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

This is the second stored procedure `tbl_pref` which is used in the same function:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tbl_pref]
    @userID int,
    @preferenceID int
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_preferences(userID, preferenceID) 
    VALUES (@userID, @preferenceID)
END
```

Comment: The error is pretty obvious. The sproc expects a parameter called UserID. Your calling code does not supply any parameter called UserID.

Comment: The preferenceName here is a checkbox list in which I have already entered the values from the database. PLs help.

Comment: But the userID is an autogenerated column.

Comment: You don't seem to pass the parameter for UserID in your code. Is it an identity column?

Comment: @user2920046 - It's still expected in the proc definition, and missing in the code. This is why you see the error message.

Comment: > Procedure or function 'SHOWuser' expects parameter '@preferenceName', which was not supplied.

Comment: @user2920046, there are 5 parameters in your SP but your code has only 4. That's why the error.

Comment: could u pls tell me the proper coding in wither sproc or C# for both userID and preferenceName

Comment: In that case, pass 0 to the UserID if it is an identity column.

Comment: @Aishvarya ya thats true but userId is an autogenerated column and preferenceName is a list of values already entered in the database. I am using here the stuff query for combining two tables tbl_user(userName,password,emailAddress)==[These values are to entered by the user] and tbl_pref_master(prefID,preferenceName)==[I have already entered these values in the database].

Comment: Your heading says you are trying to insert data into a SQL Server database but the stored procedure you have given here is only a select statement. Is this your complete code?

Comment: @Deepshikha- Thanku for realising my mistake. Pls see the code i have changed the sproc. but still the error remains the same

Comment: @Aishvarya pls help me with the code for passing 0 to the userID. Like is it passing null value in this way. "SET userid=null;" The sproc is actually not accepting this. Pls help

Comment: I have changes the code as well as the stored procedure. Now the error generated is ERROR:  object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Procedure expects parameter which was not supplied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368642/procedure-expects-parameter-which-was-not-supplied)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your stored procedure expects 5 parameters as input

```
@userID int, 
@userName varchar(50), 
@password nvarchar(50), 
@emailAddress nvarchar(50), 
@preferenceName varchar(20)
```

So you should add all 5 parameters to this SP call:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "SHOWuser";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID",userID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", emailAddress);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preferenceName", preferences);
    dbcon.Open();
```

PS: It's not clear what these parameter are for. You don't use these parameters in your SP body so your SP should looks like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SHOWuser] AS BEGIN ..... END
```

Comment: Pls see the code again. I ve edited both the code and stored procedure. The error which comes now is like ERROR:  object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @user2920046  If you've removed parameters from STORED PROCEDURE then you should remove ALL `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` from your code also.

Comment: I have not removed any. The userName, password and emailAddress values are to be stored in the database which will be entered by the user whereas the preferenceName is to be selected by the user from the checkboxlist whose values I have already entered in the database.

Comment: @user2920046 Now you've changed first stored procedure from SELECT to INSERT so you should change `int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` to `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: In the first stored procedure I have added the insert query. It contains both the select and insert query.

Comment: I changed the "int i" as u said but the ERROR: "object reference not set to an instance of an object" still comes

Comment: may be no check null to pass to stored procedure.
better that check null and pass dbnull.value

Answer (score 190):

In my case I received this exception even when all parameter values were correctly supplied but the type of command was not specified :

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

This is obviously not the case in the question above, but exception description is not very clear in this case, so I decided to specify that.

Comment: I wonder why the exception specifies that a parameter was missing though? Maybe since the `CommandType` was not set to `StoredProcedure`, it doesn't send any parameters that were added to the `SqlCommand`?

Comment: @Alex Krotnyi your answer helped me realize in my case it was the output parameter that was expected. I'd forgotten this bit of code in .net code behind [[cmd.Parameters.Add("@OutParamNameHere", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;]]

Comment: I just encountered this issue. 
For me: 
`$cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;` 
should be:
`$Cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure`
or
`$Cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]'StoredProcedure'` 

Sorry, I'm not much of a programmer, so I can't tell you why this is.

Answer (score 46):

I came across this issue yesterday, but none of the solutions here worked exactly, however they did point me in the right direction.

Our application is a workflow tool written in C# and, overly simplified, has several stored procedures on the database, as well as a table of metadata about each parameter used by each stored procedure (name, order, data type, size, etc), allowing us to create as many new stored procedures as we need without having to change the C#.

Analysis of the problem showed that our code was setting all the correct parameters on the `SqlCommand` object, however once it was executed, it threw the same error as the OP got.

Further analysis revealed that some parameters had a value of `null`. I therefore must draw the conclusion that `SqlCommand` objects ignore any `SqlParameter` object in their `.Parameters` collection with a value of `null`.

There are two solutions to this problem that I found.

1. In our stored procedures, give a default value to each parameter, so from `@Parameter int` to `@Parameter int = NULL` (or some other default value as required).
2. In our code that generates the individual `SqlParameter` objects, assigning `DBNull.Value` instead of `null` where the intended value is a SQL `NULL` does the trick.

The original coder has moved on and the code was originally written with Solution 1 in mind, and having weighed up the benefits of both, I think I'll stick with Solution 1. It's much easier to specify a default value for a specific stored procedure when writing it, rather than it always being `NULL` as defined in the code.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: this is what happened to me... i was passing null as one of the parameters

Comment: Perfectly solved me problem. I had 100+ parameters to my stored procedure and I couldn't figure why I was getting this error while all parmeters were supplied. Many thanks

Comment: I had 25 parameters, all supplied, and got this error on various parameters due to varying test data sets.  What seemed to be inconsistent results was random null values. Using *solution 1* did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I got the error on output parameter even though I was setting it correctly on C# side I figured out I forgot to give a default value to output parameter on the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
(
                @UserID int,
                @ReturnValue int = 0 output --Previously I had @ReturnValue int output
)
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, It was returning one output parameter and was not Returning any value.
So changed it to

```
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.ExecuteScalar();
```

and then it was throwing size error. so had to set the size as well

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Name",SqlDbType.NVarChar);
param.Size = 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

After researching, I realized that I did not specify

```
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

After adding this, my application ran properly.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I was passing all the parameters but one of the parameter my code was passing a null value for string.

Eg: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);`

in the above case, if the data type of userName is string, I was passing userName as null.