# Procedure or function 'sp_getchech' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a very simple stored proc which selects records based on ID provided by user.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getcheck]
@ID int
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.

SET NOCOUNT ON;
If NOT EXISTS(select * from mytable where ID=@ID)
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR (
    'The ID you entered %d is invalid',
    11,
    1,
    @ID);
  END
END
```

What we would like to do is have user enter an ID and check to see if it exists on our database.

If yes, user is redirected to a page of his/her choice.

If no, we would like to keep user on same screen with a message that ID number entered Q1254 is invalid.

That error is raised on the stored procedure and we would like C# code to display that message on the screen for the user.

Here is that code:

```
protected void chk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountnumber.Text))
    {
        SqlConnection Conn = default(SqlConnection);

        //Read in connection String
        Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constr"].ConnectionString);
        Conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getcheck", Conn);
        //Retrieve the value of the output parameter

        //Add the output parameter to the command object
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", checknumber.Text);
        SqlParameter outPutParameter = new SqlParameter();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Retrieve the value of the output parameter

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                //we add a hidden field called IsValid to the markup and set the IsValid value in the event handler here.
                imgstatus.ImageUrl = "images/Icon_Available.gif";
                lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;

                //redirect based on value of hidden form field called evalue
                var evalue = hequipID.Value;
                if (evalue == "1")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Air.aspx?pageId=1");
                }
                if (evalue == "2")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Land.aspx?pageId=2");
                }

                //ID exists, get form fields and store db values in them:
                //txtfname.Text = (dr["FullName"].ToString());

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                //Something is wrong with this taxpayer's account.
                imgstatus.ImageUrl = "images/NotAvailable.jpg";
                lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblStatus.Text = ex.Message;
                chk.BackColor = Color.Silver;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

When I tried to run the code, I get the following error message:

`Procedure or function 'sp_getchech' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied`

Surely I am doing something wrong.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

The threads referenced is different from mine. That thread is missing some parameters.

My is not missing any parameters, therefore, not a duplicate of referenced thread.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: This should help cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: @Aamir, thanks but marc_s caught that earlier.

I just need a way to:

1, stop the page from blowing up when ID is invalid. All the user should see is the error message, not the page error out.

2, when a code ID is entered, it is not redirecting as it should. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stored procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703653/stored-procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-is-not-supplied)

Comment: Do you guys even read the issues or you just go by title.

I checked that out before posting this thread. They are not the same.

Comment: Yes they are the same, and there are [a lot of them](https://www.google.nl/search?site=&source=hp&q=Procedure+or+function+expects+parameter+which+was+not+supplied+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=Procedure+or+function+expects+parameter+which+was+not+supplied+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7238.19616.0.19903.27.27.0.0.0.0.168.2810.15j12.27.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.746...0j0i7i30i19k1j0i19k1j0i7i30k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i30i19k1.rdRb0hBghx8). The underlying problem is that you fail to supply a parameter. And most of the time because a Session or TextBox is left empty

Comment: I don't have time for all these vengeful comments. You said I failed to supply a parameter.  Are you serious? you can't possibly be referring to my thread.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are potentially sending a blank, null or empty ID to the stored proc.

Your code checks if `accountnumber.Text` is not null or empty, but then you use the value of `checknumber.Text`.

Of course this could all be discovered quite easily if you attach a debugger and look at the value you are sending to your stored procedure.

Comment: the accountnumber was a typo. My apologies to all.

That is not the reason I promise. After correcting it, same error.

Answer (score 1):

You're never telling your `SqlCommand` that this is about calling a **stored procedure** - do it like so:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getcheck", Conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: nice catch.

Stupid rookie mistake even though I have done this many times.

With that change, when I intentionally enter a wrong ID, I get the message but the page errors out. Second, when I enter the correct ID, it is not redirecting