# Convert JQuery To ForEach() Loop Throws Error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am running the below syntax which will work for just one hardcoded grid name.  I want to convert this to iterate an array of grids (as 3 additional have just been added to the page) but I get an error of

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query expects the parameter '@slm', which was not supplied.'

Now this is the syntax that works for one grid

```
    <script>
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        var GvonedataList = [];
        var slm = false;
        var prs = false;
        var rgs = false;
        var hsp = false;
        var ent = false;
        $('[id*=gvalpha]').find('tr:has(td)').each(function () {
            var gridrow = $(this);
            var colno = 2;
            var Gvonedata = {};
            slm = true;
            Gvonedata.fldslm = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
            colno = colno + 1;
            $('#cbxslm input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    if ($(this).val() == 'prs') {
                        prs = true;
                        Gvonedata.fldprs = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                        colno = colno + 1;
                    }
                    else if ($(this).val() == 'rgs') {
                        rgs = true;
                        Gvonedata.fldrgs = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                        colno = colno + 1;
                    }
                    else if ($(this).val() == 'hsp') {
                        hsp = true;
                        Gvonedata.fldhsp = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                        colno = colno + 1;
                    }
                    else if ($(this).val() == 'ent') {
                        ent = true;
                        Gvonedata.fldent = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                        colno = colno + 1;
                    }
                }
            });
            GvonedataList.push(Gvonedata);
            });
            if (GvonedataList.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("estingAjax.aspx/SaveGridData") %>',
                    data: '{Gvonedata: ' + JSON.stringify(GvonedataList) + ', slm: ' + slm + ', prs: ' + prs + ', rgs: ' + rgs + ', hsp: ' + hsp + ', ent: ' + ent + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            }
    });
</script>
```

And this is the syntax that throws the above error

```
    <script>
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        var GvonedataList = [];
        var slm = false;
        var prs = false;
        var rgs = false;
        var hsp = false;
        var ent = false;
        var grids = ["gridfirst", "gridsecond", "gridthird", "gridfourth"];
        var gridlen = grids.length;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < gridlen; i++) {
            var gridrow = $(this);
            var colno = 2;
            var Gvonedata = {};
            slm = true;
            Gvonedata.fldslm = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
            colno = colno + 1;
            $('#cbrst input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    if ($(this).val() == 'prs') {
                        prs = true;
                        Gvonedata.fldprs = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                        colno = colno + 1;
                    }
                    else if ($(this).val() == 'rgs') {
                        rgs = true;
                        Gvonedata.fldrgs = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                        colno = colno + 1;
                    }
                    else if ($(this).val() == 'hsp') {
                        hsp = true;
                        Gvonedata.fldhsp = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                        colno = colno + 1;
                    }
                    else if ($(this).val() == 'ent') {
                        ent = true;
                        Gvonedata.fldent = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                        colno = colno + 1;
                    }
                }
            });
            GvonedataList.push(Gvonedata);
            if (GvonedataList.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("estingAjax.aspx/SaveGridData") %>',
                    data: '{Gvonedata: ' + JSON.stringify(GvonedataList) + ', slm: ' + slm + ', prs: ' + prs + ', rgs: ' + rgs + ', hsp: ' + hsp + ', ent: ' + ent + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

How do I chnage my second code to get it to iterate the array and insert?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stored procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703653/stored-procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-is-not-supplied)

Comment: Where are you trying to convert to `forEach` loop?

Comment: @JohnKennedy - instead of hardcoding the grid name $('[id*=gvalpha]').find('tr:has(td)').each(function () I want to use the array of grid names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line $(this) returns the button that was clicked on:

```
var gridrow = $(this);
```

You should get a table row, from current table, like you did for 1 table in the initial code, e.g.:

```
<script>
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
    var GvonedataList = [];
    var slm = false;
    var prs = false;
    var rgs = false;
    var hsp = false;
    var ent = false;
    var grids = ["gridfirst", "gridsecond", "gridthird", "gridfourth"];
    var gridlen = grids.length;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < gridlen; i++) {
        GvonedataList = [];
        slm = false;
        prs = false;
        rgs = false;
        hsp = false;
        ent = false;
        $('[id*='+grids[i]+']').find('tr:has(td)').each(function () {
            var gridrow = $(this);
            var colno = 2;
            var Gvonedata = {};
            slm = true;
            Gvonedata.fldslm = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
            colno = colno + 1;
            $('#cbrst input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                  if ($(this).val() == 'prs') {
                    prs = true;
                    Gvonedata.fldprs = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                    colno = colno + 1;
                  }
                  else if ($(this).val() == 'rgs') {
                    rgs = true;
                    Gvonedata.fldrgs = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                    colno = colno + 1;
                  }
                  else if ($(this).val() == 'hsp') {
                    hsp = true;
                    Gvonedata.fldhsp = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                    colno = colno + 1;
                  }
                  else if ($(this).val() == 'ent') {
                    ent = true;
                    Gvonedata.fldent = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                    colno = colno + 1;
                  }
                }
            });
            GvonedataList.push(Gvonedata);
        });
        if (GvonedataList.length > 0) {
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("estingAjax.aspx/SaveGridData") %>',
                data: '{Gvonedata: ' + JSON.stringify(GvonedataList) + ', slm: ' + slm + ', prs: ' + prs + ', rgs: ' + rgs + ', hsp: ' + hsp + ', ent: ' + ent + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
          });
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

UPD: Also all the variables should be set back to defaults on every iteration.

Comment: Judging by your first code comment above does this explain why this line if ($(this).prop('checked')) does not only select the "checked" rows of the grid, it grabs all?