# Procedure or function 'select1_customer' expects parameter '@Customerid', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

This is my code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            mytable = new DataTable();
            mytable.Columns.Add("Customerid");
            mytable.Columns.Add("Customername");
            mytable.Columns.Add("Contactname");
            mytable.Columns.Add("Address");
            mytable.Columns.Add("Mobile");

            GridView1.DataSource = mytable;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Table_3", con);


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select1_customer", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;              
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(mytable);
            GridView1.DataSource = mytable;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Procedure or function 'select1_customer' expects parameter '@Customerid', which was not supplied. it was my error

Comment: you havent passed the input parameters for select1_customer

Comment: i have passed the parameters in sp

Comment: remove parameter from sp and it should work fine if you just want select query and if you want filter or logic pass parameter in it for tut check aspsnippets website

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stored procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703653/stored-procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-is-not-supplied)

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customerid", required value);
```

Try,

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select1_customer", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customerid", "value_for_CustomerID");             
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(mytable);
GridView1.DataSource = mytable;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: bt i have only select the sp for view a grid table

Comment: even though your stored procedure does "Select", it might have created with '@CustomerID' parameter in it. So in C# you are suppose to pass value to that procedure. 

Or 

you can make changes in your stored procedure by setting default value to it based on data type of the parameter, Like @Customerid = ''(if varchar)