# The parameterized query '(@role nvarchar(5),@count int)StudentProcedure @role,@count OUT' expects the parameter '@count', which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller

//Student Controller

```
public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Emial { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
```

//StudentConroller (Here I called Stored Procedure)

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ApplicationDbClass applicationDbClass;
    public AccountController()
    {
        applicationDbClass = new ApplicationDbClass();
    }
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Student student)
    {
            var v1 = new SqlParameter();
            v1.ParameterName = "@role";
            v1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
            v1.Value = "Admin";

            var v2 = new SqlParameter();
            v2.ParameterName = "@count";
            v2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;

            try
            {
                var result = applicationDbClass.Students.SqlQuery("StudentProcedure @role,@count OUT", v1, v2).ToArray(); 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                var m = e.Message;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Student");
    }
}
```

//Stored procedure

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE StudentProcedure
    @role NVARCHAR(30),
    @count INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @count=COUNT(dbo.Students.Role) 
    FROM dbo.Students
    WHERE Role=@role;
END
```

//DbContext Class

```
public class ApplicationDbClass : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbClass() : base()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbClass>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbClass>());
        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LogTable> LogTables { get; set; }
    }
```

// Here I am using code first approch to deal with database using entity framework to call the user created stored procedure.  If I make some changes on stored procedure it will not refected directly. Please give me any solution to refects the changes.

Comment: `@count` is an `OUTPUT` parameter, so you must mark the `.Direction` accordingly.

Comment: Add `v2.ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Output;`. The default direction I input.

Comment: I get this exception "Procedure or function StudentProcedure has too many arguments specified".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stored procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703653/stored-procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-is-not-supplied)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters in this way also

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StudentProcedure", cnn);
cmd.Connection = cnn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", "Admin");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@count", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@count"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

string Query = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
```

Here my goal is to show how to pass normal and output parameter to procedure.

Comment: Please dont use `AddWithValue` . See this https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here in your code.

You should set the default value for your `output` parameter. Otherwise `C#` code will throw an exception if you do not set default value to your output parameter. So your stored procedure should look like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE StudentProcedure
    @role NVARCHAR(30),
    @count INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @count=COUNT(dbo.Students.Role) 
    FROM dbo.Students
    WHERE Role=@role;   
    SELECT @count;
END
GO
```

And the second issue is you've forgot to set `Direction` of your output parameter:

```
var sqlParameter_Role = new SqlParameter("@role", "Admin");

var sqlParameter_Count = new SqlParameter();
sqlParameter_Count.ParameterName = "@count";
sqlParameter_Count.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
sqlParameter_Count.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

var result = db.Database
    .SqlQuery<ResultForStudentProcedure>("dbo.StudentProcedure @role" 
        , sqlParameter_Role 
        , sqlParameter_Count)
    .ToList();


public class ResultForStudentProcedure
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not me but IMO there is no good reason to set a default value for an output parameter especially if the passed parameter value (default or otherwise) is completely ignored. Nor is there an obvious reason to also generate a resultset from the procedure.

Comment: @Smor `C#` code will throw an exception if you do not set default value to your output parameter.