# How to Insert null value for a nullable integer column to SQL Table by C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-4.5

I am reading a CSV file via OleDBConnection, retrieving integer values for some fields there and saving to SQL DB. I have a column named `Q3` which is **nullable**.

When I try the following below, it works well:

```
create table #temp (num int);
insert into #temp (num) values (null);
```

However, I have the following code in asp.net 4.5, which is not working:

```
SQLDatabase sql = new SQLDatabase();
SQLParamList sqlParams = new SQLParamList();

int? Q3 = null;
Q3 = CheckNumericContent(r, dr, "Q3"); //Q3 empty cell for the row in csv.
sqlParams.Add("@Q3", Q3); //Q3 is still null here.
sql.ExecStoredProcedureDataTable("[spInsert_Data]", sqlParams);
```

The code of `CheckNumericContent` function is here:

```
private int? CheckNumericContent(int r, DataRow dr, string columnname)
{
    int ret = -1;
    if (dr[columnname] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr[columnname].ToString()))
    {
        try
         {
             if (!Int32.TryParse(dr[columnname].ToString(), out ret))
             {
                 ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + string.Format("Row {0}: {1) is not numeric.\n", r.ToString(), columnname);
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "some error: "+ex.ToString(); 
         }
          return ret;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }          
}
```

**spInsert_Data stored Procedure is (Sql Server 2014):**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsert_Data
   @Q3 int
AS BEGIN
   insert into tblMyData (Q3) values (@Q3);
END
```

This code works well unless Q3 is null. When Q3 is null, which means there is no data for Q3 for a row in the CSV, it is giving the error:

> Procedure or function 'spInsert_Data' expects parameter '@Q3', which
> was not supplied.

Picture of the error is on the below. What is wrong and how can I fix it? Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stored procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703653/stored-procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-is-not-supplied)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `DBNull.Value`.

```
int? Q3 = null;
Q3 = CheckNumericContent(r, dr, "Q3"); //Q3 empty cell for the row in csv.
if (Q3.HasValue)
{
    sqlParams.Add("@Q3", Q3);
}
else
{
    sqlParams.Add("@Q3", DBNull.Value)
}
sql.ExecStoredProcedureDataTable("[spInsert_Data]", sqlParams);
```

`DBNull.Value` can be used to set a null value in the database. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> If a database field has missing data, you can use the DBNull.Value
>   property to explicitly assign a DBNull object value to the field.

Comment: if ( drpselected.SelectedValue == "") 
{ 
     values.add(DBNull.Value); 
} 
else
{
    values.add(drpselected.SelectedValue);
}

Comment: Syntactically much simpler:

    sqlParams.Add("@Q3", (object)Q3 ?? DBNull.Value);

Answer (score 1):

Just set it to null as the default. But you'll want to **not** insert when that value is null (at least this is what i'd expect)... so add an `IF`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsert_Data (@Q3 int = null)
AS BEGIN
IF (@Q3 is not null)
BEGIN
   insert into tblMyData (Q3) values (@Q3);
END
END
```

Comment: There are other columns in the original, so even though Q3 is null I should add the row. I'll try your solution

Comment: Your solution works, just I don't want to update the SP since it is also used by other pages. Thanks a lot for sharing this, appreciated.

Comment: No sweat! @ErayBalkanli