# Stored procedure expects parameter id value which is not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table students with columns

```
id primary key, firstname, lastname, birthdate, gender, phone, address.
```

I am working with WebForms in ASP.NET.

I have this stored procedure.

```
create procedure spAddStudents
(
    @id int
    , @firstname nvarchar(50)
    , @lastname nvarchar(50)
    , @birthdate date
    , @gender nvarchar(5)
    , @phone nvarchar(50)
    , @address nvarchar(200)  
)  
as  
Begin  
    insert into students
    values (@id, @firstname, @lastname, @birthdate, @gender, @phone, @address)  
End
```

In the webform I wrote this code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddStudents",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",txtId.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname",txtFirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname",txtLastName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate",txtBirthDate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender",ddlGender.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone",txtPhone.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address",txtAddress.Text);

con.Open();
int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (k != 0)
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Record inserted successfully";
}
```

After filling the form with data when click on ADD button it should add data to table but it is giving me error saying that:

> stored procedure expects parameter id value which is not supplied.

I tried making the id as autoincrement value. and removed the id field form the form. This time when I press add button it is saying that stored procedure expecting value for firstname which is not supplied.

Where is the mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @LMS, will recommend **not to use** `.AddWithValue()` as the mismatch of datatype in your Stored Procedure and SqlParameter you passed in for `@id`. You may read on this [article](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Thank you.

Comment: And further best practices, don't prefix you SP with sp. And you should always list the columns you are inserting into. And you need to pause your debugger on the Execute command and inspect your parameter values (after removing AddWithValue).

Comment: In c# you converted all variables to text.  If they are coming from text box then do someting like this : int.Parse(txtId.Text)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stored procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703653/stored-procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-is-not-supplied)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the insert command inside of the stored procedure is missing the id.

As noted, you would be better to use strong type conversion here.

and as noted, `paramaters.Add` is preferred here.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddStudents", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtId.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text;
    . etc .etc .etc

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Note how we did FORCE the command type - perhaps give that a try. I think the issue is in the stored procedure code.