# SQL output procedure C# ExecuteNonQuery "parameter not supplied"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

This question has not been already answered. Similar question "[Stored procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703653/stored-procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-is-not-supplied)" is a different question about how to code the request in C#. My issue is an SQL issue. I am getting an error

> parameter not supplied

inconsistently. If I am executing a stored procedure from SSMS with the following script, it works fine with the expected output:

```
declare @p5 int
execute dbo.aspCreateQuote @customerID = 13,@itemList='text goes here',@quoteID = @p5 output;
select @p5
```

The following script (from SQL Server Profiler) executed by an app does not work:

```
declare @p5 int
set @p5=NULL
exec sp_executesql N'psa.dbo.aspCreateQuote',N'@customerID int,@itemList varchar(3774), @quoteID int output'
,@customerID=13
,@itemList='[xml block of text goes here]',
@quoteID=@p5 output
select @p5
```

It generates the error:

> 'aspCreateQuote' expects parameter '@customerID', which was not supplied.

Clearly the parameter is supplied and is not null, so what's wrong?

The second script is generated by C# / ASP.NET `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` method as revealed by SQL Server Profiler. If there is something wrong with the script, then how to get C# to generate the correct script?

Here is the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aspCreateQuote]
    @customerID int,
    @itemList xml,
    @quoteID int OUTPUT 
AS
    INSERT INTO Quotes (CustomerID, Items) 
    VALUES (@customerID, @itemList);

    SET @quoteID = (SELECT MAX(QuoteID) FROM Quotes WHERE CustomerID = @customerID);

    RETURN @quoteID
```

And here is the C#:

```
    SqlCommand sp = new SqlCommand("dbo.aspCreateQuote", cnx);
    SqlParameterCollection parameterSet = sp.Parameters;
    SqlParameter param;

    param = new SqlParameter("@customerID", SqlDbType.Int);
    param.Value = Convert.ToInt32(cartID);
    parameterSet.Add(param);

    param = new SqlParameter("@itemList", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    param.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlItems) ? "" : xmlItems;
    parameterSet.Add(param);

    param = new SqlParameter("@quoteID", SqlDbType.Int);
    param.Value = 0;
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    parameterSet.Add(param);

    sp.ExecuteNonQuery();

    quoteID = (Int32)sp.Parameters["@QuoteID"].Value;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also `SET @quoteID = (SELECT MAX(QuoteID) FROM Quotes WHERE CustomerID = @customerID);` is absolutely wrong and will give incorrect results under high concurrency. Instead you need `SET @quoteID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();`. And if you have a list you should store it in separate rows, not in an XML blob

Comment: I am not worried at the moment about how to construct the return value. I am asking what is wrong with the script that C# is generating.

Comment: No, other questions about calling stored procedures are mostly about getting the parameters and code syntax to work.  This is specifically about why C# auto-generated procedure call does not work when using the same parameters and values as another call.

Comment: And the *specific* answer to this is the same: because `sp.CommandType` is wrong. The auto-generated statement is an ad-hoc batch to `sp_executesql` of just `dbo.aspCreateQuote`, which obviously doesn't have the `exec` statement correct. I might add that the result from the Profiler is actually just a *representation* of what a call to `sp_executesql` would look like, it actually calls `sp_executesql` using RPC. But what you really wanted was a direct call to your procedure, not to `sp_executesql`

Answer (score 1):

You need to list the parameters as part of the `@stmt` value because that needs to be the exact SQL you wish to execute e.g.

```
declare @p5 int;
set @p5 = null;
exec sp_executesql N'dbo.aspCreateQuote @customerID, @itemList, @quoteID'
  , N'@customerID int, @itemList varchar(3774), @quoteID int output'
  , @customerID=13
  , @itemList='[xml block of text goes here]'
  , @quoteID=@p5 output;
select @p5;
```

FYI, using the `RETURN` statement for returning user values is not its intended use. The `RETURN` statement is for returning a status of the stored procedure.

Comment: You missed the point: OP is not executing that directly, SqlClient is. The solution is to set `CommandType` so it goes over RPC instead of an ad-hoc batch