# Procedure or function .. expects parameter ... which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

NOTE: Although I give it the same title, this is a distinctly different question from the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703653/stored-procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-is-not-supplied) because it is a totally different cause of the error.  Hence, I supply different source code that causes the same error message, but under different circumstances.

I have code that uses SqlClient to execute a stored procedure, and am getting this every time I run it.

```
SqlConnection connString = new SqlConnection ("Data Source = (LocalDb) \\ MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = codadb; Integrated Security = True");
connString.Open();
                    
var command = connString.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "[coda].[ACCOUNT_ADD_NEW]";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountNameParam", "Test");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailParam", "test@abc.com");
var acctid = new SqlParameter("@accountidParam", SqlDbType.BigInt);
acctid.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
command.ExecuteNonQuery ();
long acct_idnum = Convert.ToInt64(acctid.Value);
connString.Close ();
```

Comment: Incorrect!  That post which I already saw, poses a completely different cause for the same error message.  Hence the different source code, and asked as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, I missed setting the command type to Stored Procedure:

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Because it was not set to `StoredProcedure`, the client treated it as a standard SQL statement - and because the stored procedure requires parameters, it complains that it is missing, even though during runtime debugging I can see the parameters filled out on the `command` object.

Comment: Heads up: `AddWithValue` can also have its quirks with messing up resolving database-types.