# Stored procedure showing an error" Procedure or function 'Dlete_Selected' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have called a stored procedure with parameters but it showing an error

> Procedure or function 'Dlete_Selected' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[Delete_Selected]
    (@id bigint)
AS
    DELETE FROM Properties 
    WHERE Id = @id
```

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnDeleteSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    cmd.CommandText = "Delete_Selected";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Request.QueryString["id"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    DataTable dtb = dboMrk.GetDataTableFrmDB(cmd);

    if (dtb.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dtlstdata.DataSource = dtb;
        dtlstdata.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stored procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703653/stored-procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-is-not-supplied)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368642/procedure-expects-parameter-which-was-not-supplied

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Clear(); remove this and also please convert the value to big int

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

You delete all parameters you just added.

Answer (score 1):

parameters are cleared just after inserted.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Request.QueryString["id"]);
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

you need to remove `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Modify Your code,

You have passed `Request.QueryString["id"]` which returns String value.
and in sp you have specified big int type.

So convert it, like, `Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["id"])`

and also add one line,

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

after this line

```
cmd.CommandText = "Dlete_Selected";
```

Hopefully, this will work for you.
After doing this if you stuck anywhere then plz comment. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void btnDeleteSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;


    cmd.CommandText = "Dlete_Selected";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Request.QueryString["id"]);
    //cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    DataTable dtb = dboMrk.GetDataTableFrmDB(cmd);

    if (dtb.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dtlstdata.DataSource = dtb;
        dtlstdata.DataBind();
    }
}
```