# Procedure or function 'sp_Lab_InsertBiologicalPersonnel' expects parameter '@IcNumber', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, angular

I am trying to insert data into a SQL Server database by calling a stored procedure, but I am getting the error

> Procedure or function 'sp_Lab_InsertBiologicalPersonnel' expects parameter '@IcNumber', which was not supplied

My stored procedure is called `sp_Lab_InsertBiologicalPersonnel`. I already check many time if there something missing, but still get same error, even make comparison with old code which is working. But for my code it say that error.

This is my C# code

```
public static PostApiResponse InsertBiologicalPersonel(Adapter ad, BiologicalPersonelInsert request, int creatorUserId)
{
    var response = new PostApiResponse();

    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_Lab_InsertBiologicalPersonnel", ad.SQLConn, ad.SQLTran))
        {
            SqlParameter Param = new SqlParameter();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = request.biologicalId, ParameterName = "@biologicalId" });
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = request.IcNumber, ParameterName = "@IcNumber"  });
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = request.Position, ParameterName = "@Position" });
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Value = creatorUserId, ParameterName = "@IdUserCreator" });

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    response.ResponseMessage = reader.GetString(0);
                    response.ReturnCode = reader.GetInt32(1);
                    response.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(2));
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
        //string context = Common.ToStr(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
        //clsErrorLog.ErrorLog(context, e);
    }

    return response;
}
```

And this is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Lab_InsertBiologicalPersonnel] 
    @biologicalId INT,
    @IcNumber INT ,
    @Position NVARCHAR(50),
    @IdUserCreator  INT 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ReturnCode Int
    DECLARE @ReturnMessage NVARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @Identity INT

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Lab_BiologicalPersonnel]
                ([Id]
                --,[Name]
                ,[IcNumber]
                ,[Position]
                ,[IdUserCreator]
                ,[IsDeleted]
                ,[IsEnabled])
    VALUES
                (@biologicalId
                --,@Name
                ,@IcNumber 
                ,@Position 
                ,@IdUserCreator 
                ,0
                ,1)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnCode = 1
        SET @ReturnMessage = 'Insert Fail' 
        SET @Identity = 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnCode = 0
        SET @ReturnMessage = 'Insert Success' 
        SET @Identity = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())
    END

    SELECT @ReturnMessage, @ReturnCode, @Identity
END
```

Please help me explain in quite simple, I'm a newbie in programming.

Comment: `request.IcNumber` is `null`. You need to translate `null` to `DBNull.Value` or `SqlCommand` won't send the parameter. I'm trying to find an existing answer but the questions I'm finding about this error only mention `DBNull` in comments, not the answer. Maybe someone else can find it and mark this as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Procedure expects parameter which was not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368642/procedure-expects-parameter-which-was-not-supplied)

Comment: I'm also curious why `@@ROWCOUNT` would be `0` if an error was not thrown, ergo the whole `IF` is pointless