# Expects parameter '@UserId', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using VS 2016, SQL Server 2016, .NET Core 5.0.

I get the error:

> Procedure or function 'SPUpdateUser' expects parameter '@UserId', which was not supplied.

This is the code:

```
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", Convert.ToInt32(user.UserId)));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirth", user.DateOfBirth));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserNames", user.UserNames));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserLastNames", user.UserLastNames));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserPlatformName", user.UserPlatformName));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserPassword", user.UserPassword));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserGender", user.UserGender));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserDocumentNumber", Convert.ToInt32(user.UserDocumentNumber)));
                        
await dataContext.Users.FromSqlRaw("SPUpdateUser", parameters.ToArray()).ToListAsync();
```

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPUpdateUser]
    (@UserId INTEGER,
     @DateOfBirth DATE,
     @UserNames NVARCHAR(30),
     @UserLastNames NVARCHAR(30), 
     @UserPlatformName VARCHAR(30),
     @UserPassword NVARCHAR(15),
     @UserGender NVARCHAR(9),
     @UserDocumentNumber INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Users
    SET DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth,
        UserNames = @UserNames,
        UserLastNames = @UserLastNames,
        UserPlatformName = @UserPlatformName,
        UserPassword = @UserPassword,
        UserGender = @UserGender,
        UserDocumentNumber = @UserDocumentNumber
    WHERE  
        UserId = @UserId                
END
```

In Postman, I am sending:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "dateOfBirth": "1980-1-1",
    "userNames": "James",
    "userLastNames": "Rodriguez",
    "userPlatformName": "1",
    "userPassword": "222",
    "userGender": "Masculino",
    "userDocumentNumber": 1,
    "relatives": []
}
```

The stored procedure must return a value?

That expected parameter... was not supplied in the request?

I tried the suggeste solution:

```
            var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", Convert.ToInt32(user.UserId)));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirth", user.DateOfBirth));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserNames", user.UserNames));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserLastNames", user.UserLastNames));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserPlatformName", user.UserPlatformName));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserPassword", user.UserPassword));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserGender", user.UserGender));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserDocumentNumber", Convert.ToInt32(user.UserDocumentNumber)));
                        
            await dataContext.Users.FromSqlRaw("EXEC SPUpdateUser @UserId = @UserId, " +
                "@DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth, " +
                "@UserNames = @UserNames, " +
                "@UserLastNames = @UserLastNames, " +
                "@UserPlatformName = @UserPlatformName, " +
                "@UserPassword = @UserPassword, " +
                "@UserGender = @UserGender, " +
                "@UserDocumentNumber = @UserDocumentNumber", parameters.ToArray()).ToListAsync();
```

and comes out this error:

```
The required column 'UserId' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation
```

Comment: You need to send it as `CommandType.StoredProcedure` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368642/procedure-expects-parameter-which-was-not-supplied. This is difficult to do with EF as far as I recall. Alternatively just do `EXEC SPUpdateUser @UserId = @UserId, @DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth.....`

Comment: We do not store passwords or send them over the wire as plain text!

Comment: @Charlieface The required column 'UserId' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation

Comment: Well your stored procedure doesn't return anything, so perhaps just do `dataContext.ExecuteSqlRaw` instead. Or you can return the data with `OUTPUT inserted.*` after the `SET` before the `WHERE`